# How to smoothly match the terrain with a road reference in blender

Tags: python, scripting

I connected the terrain using "Shrinkwrap" as a road base in Blender. However, it is not as smooth as the areas marked in red. I'm curious about a script or method to smooth it out.
[image]

Comment: @quellenform: i think that's a typical geometry nodes case ;)

Comment: The upcoming Blender 3.5 has a *Blur Attribute* node. This could be used to smooth the terrain together with the *Geometry Proximity* node. -- Or you could try to use the *Geometry Proximity* node or the *Vertex Weight Proximity* modifier to create a vertex group for the *Shrink Wrap* modifier (not sure if this works well)

Answer (score 1):

A quick and dirt method is to apply the shrinkwrap modifier, then have a fast pass of smooth brush in sculpt mode.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
So, how to write a script that only smooths the surrounding terrain of the road?